# how to adjust width in twitter bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question about Twitter Bootstrap. I have this PSD i want to covert into responsive html, the width of the design is just 1024px but the default @media (min-width: 1200px) if Bootstrap is 1170px. I tried doing

```
.container {
   width: 1024px;
}
```

and

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.container {
   width: 1024px;
}
```

but still i cant overwrite the default width of the media query of bootstrap if the screen is 1200px or more. how can i change this?  thanks in advance

Comment: Change every `@media (min-width: 1200px) {` to `@media (min-width: 1024px) {`.

Comment: then the size of the container is still 1170px. I just changed the media query.

Comment: do you have other overrides that are working? if not not make sure your .css file is called after the bootstrap

Comment: @BojanaŠekeljić hmmm didnt thought of that. Let me try that! thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is best not to changes the with would recommend using twitter bootstrap 3 the containers are set to certain width because all the columns and spans are calculated to much adjusting

Comment: yes but you can customize mixins and variables in .less, it s very easy